# Mustache: Check for variable in current context only

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm using the Mustache template engine in a project, and I've run in to an issue where I have the same attribute name in different contexts, and I'm wondering if there is a way to specify only the attribute from the local context, without changing the name of the attribute.

**Consider having this data:**

```
{
   title: 'Hello World',
   href: 'http://example.com',
   socials: [
      {
         label: 'Twitter',
         href: 'http://twitter.com'
      },
      {
         label: 'Facebook',
      }
   ]
}
```

The issue here is that the href attribute is available in two different contexts which will cause problems if you try to use this conditionally, **like this**:

```
<div>
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <a href="{{href}}">{{href}}</a>
   <ul>
      {{#socials}}
         <li>
            {{#href}}
               <!--- In here http://twitter.com will be used for the first Social,
               but for Facebook it will use http://example.com.
               For Facebook, this value should be empty. --->

               <a href="{{href}}">{{label}}</a>
            {{/href}}

            {{^href}}
               <!--- This will never be rendered --->
               {{label}}               
            {{/href}}
         </li>
      {{/socials}}
   </ul>
</div>
```

Hopefully this demonstrates my issue. What I want is to check ONLY the current context for the variable, not check the parent context as well.

I know I can use `{{.}}` to access the current context, but is there a way to access a specific variable in the current context? For example, `{{.href}}` (which I have tried, but does not work...)

Comment: This sounds like something that might not be supported, see https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/159

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation @kimbo, I was afraid so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a closed issue](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/159) about this in the mustache.js repo in GitHub. The consensus there is that it is not supported and likely won't be implemented.

Seems like renaming `href` may be your best option. (See somewhat related discussion on [this other GitHub issue](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/399)).

Comment: Thank you - Yeap, will have to rename :/. A bit irritating but at least there is a workaround using Handlebars as mentioned by Chrisp.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by kimbo is correct: renaming `href`, either in the top-level object or in the objects nested within `socials` (but not both), is one way in which you can change the data in order to solve the problem. For completeness, I will mention two other possibilities which are about equally good/bad:

1. Add a falsy `href` attribute everywhere it is unset.

```js
{
   title: 'Hello World',
   href: 'http://example.com',
   socials: [
      {
         label: 'Twitter',
         href: 'http://twitter.com'
      },
      {
         label: 'Facebook',
         href: undefined
      }
   ]
}
```

2. Wrap the top-level properties so the `socials` do not fall back to them. This would require adjustments in the template as well, for example `{{top.title}}` instead of just `{{title}}`.

```js
{
   top: {
       title: 'Hello World',
       href: 'http://example.com',
   },
   socials: [
      {
         label: 'Twitter',
         href: 'http://twitter.com'
      },
      {
         label: 'Facebook',
      }
   ]
}
```

This is admittedly an area where Mustache is currently lacking. [Power lambdas](https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/135) would allow for a masking operator that ensures only the top scope is visible, so we could do something like this instead:

```
<div>
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <a href="{{href}}">{{href}}</a>
   <ul>
      {{#socials}}
         <li>
            {{#mask.href}}
               <a href="{{mask.href}}">{{label}}</a>
            {{/mask.href}}
            {{^mask.href}}
               {{label}}               
            {{/mask.href}}
         </li>
      {{/socials}}
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your codebase, you might consider using Handlebars. It's a superset of Moustache, [providing the functionality you're after](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#evaluation-context):

```
{{this.href}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Handlebars is not an option in this project unfortunately, but that's the ideal solution.